# Permanently change the IP address of an interface in Linux with Python

Tags: python, linux, networking

I want to change permanently the `IP address` of a specific interface in `Ubuntu Linux` using `Python`.

So far I have managed to change the `IP address` using `pyroute2` but the problem is that those changes are not permanent and the next time the server is rebooted it will get back the IP address configured in the configuration file, in my case `/etc/network/interfaces`.

My code so far is the following:

```
import pyroute2

ipdb = pyroute2.IPDB()
with ipdb.interfaces.eno1 as eno1:
    eno1.del_ip('192.168.178.1/24')
    eno1.add_ip('192.168.178.22/24')
```

If I execute this script under root user it properly changes my IP address to `192.168.178.22` but if I reboot the machine or in case of a power failure `Linux` will look into its network configuration file and will restore the old `IP address`.

I know I can write the file with Python but was hoping that this would be possible with some external library.

Is there a way to save these settings permanently or what's the best practice in my case?

Comment: This would be a bit more involved than your example, but you might be able to solve this in system-friendly way with [python-networkmanager](https://pythonhosted.org/python-networkmanager/). See also [dbus NetworkManager API](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/1.2/spec.html).